# Completeness of the space of Riemann integrable functions under $\left \| . \right \|_{\infty}$ on $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I read a proof about this topic at this site and was convinced with it , then I tried to construct a cauchy sequence of functions to see how things apply . Now I'm confused.

The sequence I constructed is : $f_n(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
-lnx & if & x> e^{-n}\\ 
 n& if & x\leq e^{-n}
\end{matrix}\right.$

I proved that this sequence is cauchy and that it belongs to the mentioned space . For the limit I got that $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)=-lnx$
almost everywhere. But $f$ is not bounded on $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$

Did I miss or mess with something ??

Comment: Are you sure it's Cauchy? It looks to me like $||f_n - f_m|| = |m-n|$.

Comment: Yeahh , made a calc mistake , thanks

Comment: I have a question , is there a way to find the completion of some normed space ?

Comment: No worries. And I think it would be very useful for you to go back over your previous work and spot exactly where you made your first wrong deduction or claim. When I make a goof I find that process to be a little bit embarrassing but good for sharpening my instincts.

Comment: There's the totally general solution of considering the space of all Cauchy sequences, but that blows up the size of your space greatly, and can be very hard to visualize. But if you're thinking about stuff like this you might enjoy this [completion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281285/), and this [proof of non-completeness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2749641/f-max-limits-0-leq-x-leq-1x2fx-infty-is-not-complete/2749786#2749786). (That second link looks a lot like your example -- and was a real PITA to get all the details of Cauchy-ness right!)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Proof of non-completeness? This space is easily seen to be complete. It's a different _norm_ in that other question...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich - You change the norm, you have a different space. Or did you think I was posting those links as answers to this question? I wasn't -- based on the kinds of questions the OP was asking in their post and comments I thought they might get some use out of those other questions. Plus, that second link is a sequence based on taking a function that blows up and truncating it at successively higher levels, just like the OP's. It's not Cauchy here but it is under that question's norm.

Answer (score -1):

First observe that the space $R[0,1]$ of all Riemann integrable functions is a subspace of the *complete* space $B[0,1]$ formed by all bounded functions.  So $R[0,1]$ is complete iff it is closed in $B[0,1]$.

**Theorem**. $R[0,1]$ is closed in $B[0,1]$, and hence complete.

*Proof*. Given a sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ in $R[0,1]$ converging to some $f$ in $B[0,1]$, let $D_n$ be the set of points where $f_n$ is discontinuous.

It is well known that $D_n$ has measure zero, and hence so does
$$
D := \bigcup_n D_n.
$$

Notice that if $x$ is not in $D$ then each $f_n$ is continuous at $x$, and hence so is $f$.  In other words the discontinuities of $f$ lie in $D$ so $f$ is Riemann integrable.  QED